# Objective C - Filter array with predicate

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate

So I have an NMMutableArray which I try to filter using searchBar with no success, Instead of posting all my code I created a project just to understand how it works and everything I find online didn't help me understand this fully

here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableArray<Model*>* firstArry = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSArray<Model*>* secondArry = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    Model* p1 = [[Model alloc] init];
    p1.name = @"bob";
    p1.lastName = @"bdas";

    [firstArry addObject:p1];

    Model* p2 = [[Model alloc] init];
    p2.name = @"juny";
    p2.lastName = @"his";

    [firstArry addObject:p2];

    Model* p3 = [[Model alloc] init];
    p3.name = @"junay";
    p3.lastName = @"firs";

    [firstArry addObject:p3];

    Model* p4 = [[Model alloc] init];
    p4.name = @"bobov";
    p4.lastName = @"daskal";

    [firstArry addObject:p4];

    Model* p5 = [[Model alloc] init];
    p5.name = @"dima";
    p5.lastName = @"bonder";

    [firstArry addObject:p5];

    for (Model* name in firstArry){
        NSLog(@"%@",name.name);
    }

    NSString* filterWord = @"bo";

    NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"keywords.name CONTAINS[cd] %@",filterWord];
    secondArry = [firstArry filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];


    if(secondArry.count > 0){
    for (Model* name in firstArry){
        NSLog(@"%@",name.name);
    }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"second arry is empty");
    }

}
```

I want to filter the firstArry with the given filterWord and get a new array with the object which they name property contains it, how to do it and how does it work ?

Comment: You should read the [Predicate Format String Syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795) document. This is linked in the reference documentation for `NSPredicate`.

Answer (score 1):

The left side of the operator `CONTAINS[cd]`is the object the predicate is going to be applied to, which is `firstArry`. If you want to filter by `name` the key(path) is just `name`.

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd] %@",filterWord];
```

Comment: Perfect! it worked, I see also that its doesn't matter if the word is lowercased or not, but why ? what is "CONTAINS[cd]" mean ? I saw many types of operator as you said but no idia witch one to use were. is there a place were it is explaind in more ditails ?

Comment: `[c]` is case insensitive, `[d]` is diacritic insensitive. The best place is the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-SW1)